# RegEx - allow whitespace at start and end of the string with fixed length

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I am working on a regex with the following conditions:

- Can accept whitespace at start and end of the string
- Can accept hyphen in mid/end of the string
- Length of the characters should not be more than 10 and less than 8 **(excluding spaces)**

I have created below regex but somehow length validation is not working as expected.

`(^\s*?)((?!(-))([0-9-]*)){8,10}(\s*?)$`
https://regex101.com/r/aJNmqj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches too much because it first matches optional leading whitespace chars.

But when it gets to the first digit in the example string, in this part `((?!(-))([0-9-]*)){8,10}` the assertion `(?!(-)` is true and then this part `[0-9-]*` matches to the last digit in the example string.

It can then fulfill repeating the quantifier `{8,10}` as it already is at the position after the last digit in the example string where there is no `-` following and it can match optional digits.

---

You could start the pattern with optional whitespace chars followed by a digit, and then match 7-9 digits or hyphens:

```
^\s*[0-9][0-9-]{7,9}\s*$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/m8KOHY/1).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with a simple regex like this: `^(\s*?)[0-9-]{8,10}(\s*?)$`

I believe your other one didn't work because negative lookaheads can't be operated on by the quantifier `{8,10}` Fortunately, the negative lookahead isn't actually necessary.

Your regex got convoluted while you were trying to do this I bet, because it's happened to me too.

Answer (score 1):

From your original regex fragment `[0-9-]*` it looks like you want to allow only digits and dashes. Here is a solution that:

- allows 8-10 digits or dashes
- no dash in the beginning
- may have leading and trailing spaces

Code with test cases:

```js
const regex = /^(?!\s*-)\s*[0-9-]{8,10}\s*$/;
[
  '1234567',
  ' 123 456 7 ',
  '12345678',
  '1234567-',
  '123-5678',
  '-2345678',
  ' 12345678 ',
  ' 123 456 78 ',
  '12345678',
  '12345678 ',
  '12 34 56 78 ',
  '123456789',
  ' 123456789',
  ' 12 34 56 78 9',
  '1234567890',
  ' 123 456 7890',
  '12345678901'
].forEach(str => {
  let ok = regex.test(str);
  console.log('"' + str + '" ==> ' + ok);
});
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?!\s*-)` -- negative lookahead for optional spaces and dash
- `\s*` -- optional spaces
- `[0-9-]{8,10}` -- 8 to 10 digits/dashes
- `\s*` -- optional spaces
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex